# Create table with aggregate data from another table, using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, create-table

I am trying to create the tableau_table_1 table from the aggregated data of the covid_deaths table.

Here is my query...

```
CREATE TABLE tableau_table_1 AS 
SELECT 
   SUM(new_cases) AS total_cases,
   SUM(cast(new_deaths as int)) AS total_deaths, 
   SUM(cast(new_deaths as int))/SUM(New_Cases)*100 AS death_percentage 
FROM
   covid_data..covid_deaths 
WHERE continent IS NOT NULL
 -- Group By date order by 1,2
```

The error that I am showing is...

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'
```

Comment: Select ... INTO tableau_table_1 From ...    This assumes the table tableau_table_1  does NOT exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try SELECT INTO Statement

```
SELECT * INTO tableau_table_1
FROM (
   SELECT 
      SUM(new_cases) AS total_cases,
      SUM(cast(new_deaths AS int)) AS total_deaths, 
      SUM(cast(new_deaths AS int))/SUM(New_Cases)*100 AS death_percentage 
   FROM
      covid_data..covid_deaths 
   WHERE continent IS NOT NULL) AS aggregated_data;
```